# Error in persp.default(): invalid 'z' argument

Tags: r

about `persp`:

```
x <- seq(.0001, 10000, by = (10000 - .0001) / 1000)
y <- seq(.01, .5, by = (.5 - .01) / 100)

fun <- function(x, y) {
  x + y ^ 2 - 2 * y
}

persp(x = x, y = y, z = fun(x, y))
```

it returns

```
Error in persp.default(x = x, y = y, z = fun(x, y)) : 
  invalid 'z' argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In x + y^2 :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In x + y^2 - 2 * y :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

How may I solve the issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there. Just use `outer` to get a matrix using 'fun':

```
persp(x = x, y = y, z = outer(x, y, fun))
```

Comment: The reason the person below (visible only to readers with higher rep) gets the error is the single Inf value at the point where `outer(x,y,f)^2` goes to zero. Just use `z[is.infinite(z)] <- NA`  or `is.na(z) <- is.infinite(z)`.